# How to display success message after form submit?

Tags: forms, submit

In my current Laravel application all there is to do is fill out a form, so after the submission nothing else happens.

So now I'm wondering how it'd be best to display the success message and I've thought about three different ways:

1. simply redirect with a success message (where the user can review the data he just sent)
2. display a complete new page with -only- said success message
3. show a modal (which seems the worst to me)

After the form submission nothing else happens;
I don't know which is the best solution or if any of them have advantages or disadvantages compared to the others.
Maybe you have another even better idea, if so please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend a different idea.

How about creating an animation to display a loading percentage bar after having pressed the submit button, while at the same time disappearing the form. If you can make the progress bar connect to the progress of the uploading data, so much the better, otherwise an animation should do. Once the uploading is complete, you could display a checkmark *on the same page* above the progress bar (or instead of it) and display a message underneath. The message should be simple and let the user know:

- that their **data has been successfully submitted** and
- that they can now **close the tab**.

The reason I recommend not redirecting to a new page is because there is no reason to. You could stay on the same page and display a swift and smooth transition of state for the data with a few animations.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: This is a really good idea, I will wait a bit to see if I get any other ideas. Thanks to you :)

Comment: No problem! Please make sure, if you found this answer helpful, to accept it or/and upvote it. It would really help me out :)

Comment: I'd love to upvote, but my minimal reputation won't let me do it :(

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose is to let know user that their information was successfully saved:

Then, I work in this way:

- (if information has to be exact) Display a modal, with summarizing about what will be stored, and ask for accepting send it.
- After accept send information, show a charging icon, in order to show that information is not saved yet
- When you have a response from backend, first you have to be sure information is correctly stored (verify it, its not common having error in this part, but it could happen)
- Stop charging icon
- Show a pop-up for 1 or 2 seconds, then close it.

Why don't let the user review information after saving?

- user has to be responsible for sending information (is better a pre-confirm)
- if the user send incorrect information, it's better checking before sending than editing and updating
- Storing information is backend responsibility, if information is incorrect saved you have to handle it.

Disadvantages

1. simply redirect with a success message (where the user can review the data he just sent)

   - If information is already stored, the user pays less attention to checking
2. simply redirect with a success message (where the user can review the data he just sent)

   - Redirect with taking a second (time)
3. show a modal (which seems the worst to me)

   - User has to close modal (extra work)

Comment: I would rather not show a pop-up for some seconds, because the page is useless after the form was submitted.  After you said, I shouldn't show the data again, what do you say about showing a complete new page just with the success message?